# Cardinality > 0 Using BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-athena, cardinality

Previously I was able to quickly search ids with any type of value in an array by using cardinality > 0 in Athena.

Having switched over to BigQuery cardinality function is not supported. I tried to use HLL_COUNT.EXTRACT but that only gives me the cardinality. How can I filter to achieve the same result as cardinality > 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different concepts in this question:

- how to get the size of an array
- how to do HLL approximate counts

I think you want the size of an array, given the context.

This is how you check if the length of an array is more than zero:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH([1,2,3])>0, ARRAY_LENGTH([])>0, ARRAY_LENGTH(null)>0

# true, false, null
```